# magento 2: how to show selected radio box option based on database value?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I want to add the **radio boxes** in magento **admin panel.** Which will also show the selected radio box as per the value stored in the database.

I have the column in database which stores the values from the front end form like `Male` and `Female`.

Now i want to add the radio box in admin panel, which will show the radio option selected `Male` or `Female`. Based on value stored in database.

Comment: Can you please explain your question in detail?

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: still need to add all information in detail with example

Comment: @RonakChauhan i have updated my question. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I had the same problem and got the answer, you can refer here: [enter link description here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145541/magento-2-how-to-show-selected-radio-box-option-based-on-database-value)

Comment: I had same problem and got the solution you can refer it here [enter link description here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145767/magento-2-how-to-set-the-radio-option-value-programatically-by-variable-in-ad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `'value' => 'your value/ value from database'` attribute after the `values` attribute array.
 like

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'test', //your database field value instead of test
            'radios',
            [
                'label' => __('test'),
                'title' => __('test'),
                'name' => 'test',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => array(
                        array('value'=>'male','label'=>'Male'),
                        array('value'=>'female','label'=>'Female'),
                   ),
                'value' => 'value_from_func'
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Hi It's working, but when i try to save data from the same field it returns empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in form file

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'test', //your database field value instead of test
            'radios',
            [
                'label' => __('test'),
                'title' => __('test'),
                'name' => 'test',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => array(
                        array('value'=>'male','label'=>'Male'),
                        array('value'=>'female','label'=>'Female'),
                   )
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Which value you have used as male and female? I mean 1 for male and 0 for female?

Comment: @NitinPawar check updated answer

Comment: It's giving error undefined variable `$isDisabled`

Comment: remove disable update answer check it

Comment: @NitinPawar IT'S WORKING OR NOT?

Comment: No it only show the two radio box, I want the radio box selected based on the value in database

Comment: Is this field in your model which is you used n your edit.php controllerfile?

Comment: Yes i have this field in admin controller.